# Swagger запускается с приложением через студию, а без студии нет

Tags: asp.net

ASP.NET Core 8, сервер работает только если запускать через студию. Если запускать приложение отдельно, оно запускается, но swagger и сервер не работают. В чем может быть причина? Спасибо!